# How do I make breakfast when I don't have time to make breakfast?

Tags: food

I'm usually/always caught up in the morning rush hour and sometimes skip breakfast because I don't have time to cook up something and most importantly because I don't know even a bit about cooking. So what's the best way to arrange or make my favorite meals without spending much time in that rush?

Comment: What kind of food do you eat for breakfast? Are you prepared to change? Where do you live, so we know what kind of food is available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Learning how to cook and cook quickly is probably too broad a question, so let me suggest some things that count as "hacks"

- make extra dinner, keep it in the fridge, and warm it up for breakfast. Not all evening meals make a valid breakfast (or reheat well) but many do.
- prepare something in the evening that is ok for breakfast that you can just reheat in the morning. Perhaps make a lot of it on the weekend and freeze it.
- stock your home with  things that you can prepare super quickly. Instant oatmeal, frozen sausage patties, bagels, cream cheese, frozen waffles or pancakes, yogurt, granola, whatever it is you like
- keep something in your car, bike bag, backpack, briefcase, or desk that you can eat for breakfast if you somehow leave the house without eating. A protein bar, for example

You don't have to eat official breakfast food at breakfast. Eat what works for you.

Comment: As an example on part of this answer, we used to make chocolate chip waffles and freeze them. Plenty of flavor on their own and don't even need to be heated up, can be eaten with your hands while frozen. Make a big batch on the weekend and freeze them separately.

Comment: I always keep protein bars for the lazy mornings. Works fine for me.

Answer (score 5):

While I'm not a big fan of hurrying meals which not only means a considerable loss of quality of life but is also unhealthy (you could *really* just get up 15 minutes earlier, you know!), if you truly don't have enough time in the morning, you need to apply the same strategy as in many technical fields: work *asynchronously*.

That is, put eggs into the egg boiler, and set the electric kettle (and maybe the toaster) on before going into the shower. If you don't shower in the morning, make that "before you shave" or any other daily "biological morning activity".

The eggs will still take their 6 minutes, but the latency is hidden by the fact that you do something else in the mean time. Water will have boiled and only needs another 5 seconds to boil again when you come out of the shower.  The individual times for each procedure do not add up, and thus the overall duration is reduced.
Boiled eggs make a marvelous haste breakfast, too, since you can (although, again, *I recommend against it*) peel them in about 3 seconds by rolling them if you have some practice, and you can swallow them whole on your way out. Not pretty, no joy, but works for staying alive.

As a bonus, choose the clothes that you will wear the evening before, and lay them on a table or over a chair, ready to dress. This will buy you some 3 minutes "for free" which you can spend on having a real meal rather than swallowing whole eggs, for enhanced quality of life.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you can manage lunch and dinner by buying a sandwich and a ready meal for the evening.

As for breakfast, eat proper oats - buy whole rolled jumbo oats. When you get up and put the kettle on (assuming you have tea or coffee before leaving) throw a couple of tablespoons of oats in a dessert bowl or dish. When the water boils, pour over the oats so you can see a layer of water on top. Now go away and do whatever you do to get ready for work (shower, shave...etc). Check the oats - if the dish is cold, cool or warm (not hot) sprinkle over whatever you fancy - sugar, honey, berries, or nothing, then eat it. Much healthier than easy oats or instant oats, and much nicer too....

Answer (score 0):

**To make sandwiches faster [use muffin tins](http://m.instructables.com/id/10-Life-Hacks-You-Need-To-Know-For-a-Better-Summer/?ALLSTEPS):**

[image]

Pic taken from above link and source on pic.

- Take sandwich toppings and put it in the muffin tin holes the night before then refrigerate. When you wake up the toppings are already cut and organized, so making sandwiches are easier and faster.

**Make food beforehand:**

- Many foods do not have to be made the day of, they can be made days or a day before. Packaging dinner for breakfast or making a salad the night before can save you time. Restaurants/ caterers make food the day before.

Answer (score 0):

I just have either a Protein Shake or [Soylent](https://www.soylent.com/) for breakfast. Its fast an easy and does the job.